# Find all elements in javascript that do not have a data- attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to find all elements in `$('.post-content')` that do not have data attributes. I tried to say something like `if (!$('.post-content p').attr('data-example')) { ... }`

But obviously that does not work. So how would I do the following:

*Find all p tags that belong to .post-content who do NOT have a data-attribute and remove them.*

I think its very straight forward, but all the stack questions and docs, and jquery and the internet just has "how to add, how to find, how to add a value - to the data attribute"

So I was not completely clear, my apologies. In the example:

```
<div class="post-content">
  <p data-attribute="foo">
    <span data-attribute="boo">
     <p>...</p>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p> ... </p>
</div>
```

I do not want nested `p` tags, like the one you see here, where there is a nested p tag under the p tag that has a data attribute, to be removed. Just top level `p` tags that do not have a data attribute.

The solutions provided tend to remove nested and top level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not having a *particular* data attribute

You can use a combination of the [`:not()`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:not) and [`[attribute]`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/attribute_selector/attribute) selectors ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62y61v6x/1)):

```
$(".post-content p:not([data-something])").remove();
```

### Not having *any* data attributes

**A.:** You could check if there's anything in the element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) using `Object.keys()` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b22ergha/2)):

```
$(".post-content p").filter(function(){
   return Object.keys(this.dataset).length === 0;
}).remove();
```

... or you could use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
$(".post-content p").filter(function(){
   for (var prop in this.dataset) {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}).remove();
```

<sub>Note: Depending upon the browsers you need to support, `dataset` [may not be available](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset).</sub>

**B.:** You could simply iterate over the element's [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.attributes) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nm7a0gx/)):

```
$(".post-content p").filter(function(){
    return ![].some.call(this.attributes, function(attr){
        return /^data-/i.test(attr.name);
    });
}).remove();
```

<sub>See also: [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and `Array.prototype.some()`</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$('.post-content p').not('[data-example]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a specific data attribute, or just any data attribute (e.g. data-a, data-b, ... data-z, data-aa, data-ab, ...)?

If you mean a specific attribute then something like this should work:

```
$(".post-content p:not([data-example]").remove()
```

But if you mean ANY data attribute, that's a whole 'nother thing. You'd have to find all the potential elements, then enumerate each of their attribute collections (e.g. $foo[0].attributes) to see if any of their names start with "data-". If you have to do that I hope you don't have a lot of elements, it won't be very fast. Perhaps you could explain what the problem you're trying to solve is as there may be a better way to do it than this. Such as keeping a known specific attribute on those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `.dataset` property (only works in newer browers) or you can use the `.attributes` property and look for attributes that start with `"data-"`.

Here's a version that use the `attributes` list and will work in a wide range of browsers (doesn't require support for `.dataset`):

```
$(".post-content").find("*").filter(function() {
    var attrs = this.attributes;
    regex = /^data-/;
    for (var i = 0; i < attrs; i++) {
        if (regex.test(attrs[i].name)) {
            // found a "data-xxxx" attribute so return false to avoid this element
            return false;
        }
    }
    // did not find any "data-xxxx" attributes so return true to include this element
    return true;
}).remove();
```

Your question wasn't entirely clear on one point.  This code examines all descendants of `.post-content`.  If you wanted to narrow it to only certain types of objects in that hierarchy, you can change the initial selector to narrow it.