# jQuery: how to loop through elements with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several divs that looks like this:

```
<div class='popupDiv' data-layergroup='layer1'>divcontent 1</div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layergroup='layer1'>divcontent 2</div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layergroup='layer2'>divcontent 3</div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layergroup='layer2'>divcontent 4</div>
```

I'm a bit stumped as to how to loop through all popupDiv divs, and then loop through each layergroup separately. I want to end with a single array for each layergroup. I'd need something like:

```
var mainArray = [];
$('.popupDiv').each(function(){
    var tempArray = [];
    $([unique layer value]).each(function(){
        // Put div values from layergroup in tempArray
    });
    mainArray.push(tempArray);
});
return mainArray;
```

But I don't know the syntax I'm looking for. What do I do?

Comment: Id should be unique..! Invalid HTML.

Comment: Woops! Edited to use classes instead, but the question remains the same. How do I loop through each layergroup separately?

Comment: That might be ( reversed ) what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195212/find-all-elements-in-javascript-that-do-not-have-a-data-attribute.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer1'></div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer1'></div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer2'></div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer2'></div>
```

Loop through the elements

```
$('.popupDiv[data-layer]').each(function(){

});
```

to loop through each group seperately, you can use below logic

```
 //create an array to store processed data-layer type
 var dataArray = new Array();
    $('.popupDiv').each(function(){
      var dataLayer = $(this).data('layer');
      //check if data-layer already processed
      if(!dataArray.indexOf(dataLayer))
      {
         //update data array
         dataArray.push(dataLayer);
         $('.popupDiv[data-layer="'+ dataLayer +'"]').each(function(){
            //do your stuff here
         });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Just to mention: it will be a little better with `$(this).data('layer')` saved in variable, +1.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I did need to edit it somewhat: 

if(dataArray.indexOf(dataLayer) < 0) worked better for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can loop through each of the div having attribute 'data-layer' as follows:

```
$('.popupDiv').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).attr('data-layer') == 'layer' + i + 1) {

            $(this).each(function() {
                alert($(this).attr('data-layer'));
                //change this to whatever you want
            });
        }
    });
```

So this will check for 'layer1', 'layer2' and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need two each loops here. You can use  **[Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)**. you are also having duplicate IDs for divs. IDs should be unique, use class name instead:

```
$('[data-layergroup]').each(function(){
    // Do stuff with each div
    console.log($(this).data('layergroup'));//current data layer value
});
```

**For iterating over the values(FYI-BAD APPROACH):**

```
$.each($("[data-layergroup]").map(function() {  return $(this).data('layergroup');}).get(), function(index, item) {
   // item
});
```

Comment: The question is *"how to loop through each **layergroup** of divs **seperately**"*.

Comment: Milind is right and the OP didnot put the question in a right way. OP should write more div inside each popupDiv then so we can know there is smthing to loop inside each div

Comment: @doniyor: GLad you get the point. also it does not make sense to make attribute array and then iterate again over them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I have edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: @Bas: just use `$("[data-layer]").map(function() {  return $(this).data('layer');}).get()` if you only want data layer values in array.

Comment: @bas please put some more divs inside each popupDiv! This is for understanding what you are trying to loop over. Now your each div is empty. Then we think, you try to loop only those divs.

Answer (score 1):

use class instead of id:

```
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer1'></div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer1'></div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer2'></div>
<div class='popupDiv' data-layer='layer2'></div>
```

Then you can loop each layer seperatly:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  $(".popupDiv[data-layer|='layer"+i+"']").each(function(){
       // do stuff with layer i
   });
}
```

Comment: that doesnt loop from 1 to 2 and. each