# Find all elements that do not have a data- attribute without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

How can i find all element that do not have a data- attribute without using jQuery, i have seen similar to my question but they are all using jQuery. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195212/find-all-elements-in-javascript-that-do-not-have-a-data-attribute)

I need to exclude in my forEach the data-last attribute with the value of yes only.
Is there any method how to do that by using vanilla JS only? Thanks!

I've tried something like this but it is not working..

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".form-step not:[data-last="yes"]")
```

```html
<div class="form-step" data-last="no"> Stay </div>
<div class="form-step" data-last="no"> Stay </div>
<div class="form-step" data-last="yes"> Hide </div>
```

Comment: Do you need to exclude ones without that specific value (“yes”) of the attribute, any that have that attribute no matter the value, or any that have any data- attributes at all?

Comment: I need to exclude in my forEach the `data-last` attribute with the value of `yes` only.

Comment: Cool! That makes the answer simpler. May be worth stating this in the post, since there seemed to be some confusion in that regard.

Comment: aight! gotchu! i see the point

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your post! I also went ahead and added an answer more specific to your case. Also just a note that I noticed/found interesting, the selector piece of the accepted answer of the question you linked actually almost gives you what you need (the not syntax is there, just doesn’t do a specific attribute value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying! Based on your need, you’re very close. The [syntax for `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is just slightly different. Here’s the tweaked code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(‘.form-step:not([data-last="yes"])’)
```

Besides the `:` and `()` changes, notice the lack of a space, since you need it to apply to that element and not a descendent. I also had to change one of the sets of quotes so they don’t mess with each other, but I don’t believe it matters which is changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't hardcode the data attribute to exclude - it isn't possible with a single selector only. You'll need to iterate over each element and filter out those with anything in the dataset.

```js
const formStepsWithutAnyData = [...document.querySelectorAll('.form-step')]
  .filter(div => Object.keys(div.dataset).length === 0);
console.log(formStepsWithutAnyData.length);
formStepsWithutAnyData[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

```html
<div class="form-step" data-last="no"> Stay </div>
<div class="form-step" data-last="no"> Stay </div>
<div class="form-step" data-last="yes"> Hide </div>
<div class="form-step"> no data attribute </div>
```

If you *can* hardcode the attribute to exclude, all you need is `.form-step:not([data-last])` or the equivalent.

Comment: Based off the clarification in the comments, you can use the “hardcode” piece of this answer but say `data-last=“yes”`

Answer (score -1):

```js
  

document.querySelectorAll('.form-step')
  .forEach(function(element) {
    if (!element.hasAttribute('data-last')) {
      console.log(element);
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-step" data-last="no"> Stay </div>
<div class="form-step" data-last="no"> Stay </div>
<div class="form-step" data-last="yes"> Hide </div>
<div class="form-step" > No Data attribute </div>
```